# internal modules cjs is not working after yarn upgraded to 1.13.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I have a react app which is based on r[eact boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate). I am running the
following command:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --experimental-modules ./server/index.mjs
```

After upgrading yarn to 1.13.0, I am getting the following error:

```
(node:11137) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677
      module.reflect.onReady((reflect) => {
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'onReady' of undefined
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:22)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mdjahidulislam/workspace/ifs/frontend/node_modules/psl/index.js:14:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Seems like module.reflect is undefined. In which scenario it can be undefined and how I can solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. It was all about nodejs version. I had nodejs version 11.* and then I downgraded it on 10.* and it solved the issue.